# Query about the FAQ instructions to up-vote an answer

Tags: bug, status-completed, up-votes

I asked my first question today, got some great answers and so read the FAQ to learn the SO etiquette about what to do next (i.e. vote up and select an accepted answer).

Under the **How do I ask questions here?** section it states...

> As you see new answers to your question, vote up  the helpful ones by clicking the upward pointing arrow to the left of your question. Answers are normally sorted by vote score so the most highly voted answers float to the top. Other users will also vote on the answers to your question.

Shouldn't you vote up the helpful answers by clicking the up arrow to the left *of that answer*? I would have thought clicking the up arrow to the left of your question would be an attempt to vote up your own question? (which is not so cool)

Comment: Haha, good catch.  That is definitely a typo.

Comment: I wonder how long that's been wrong like that...

Comment: Although it is wrong, there's another problem with that text. What about people who don't have 15 rep?

Comment: @Hello, that is a bit of an issue.  However the reputation limits are covered on one of the next sections.  I can see how it may be confusing, but I wouldn't wanna make this section any more wordy.

Comment: @Jeff: while you're at it, could you fix the bounty section of the Meta faq?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should read:

> As you see new answers to your question, vote up the helpful ones by clicking the upward pointing arrow to the left of **the helpful answer**.

<sub>or something like that</sub>

Comment: I like words. Perhaps we could make it more wordy. Instead of "the helpful answer", maybe "the answer which was helpful or intersting and caused you joy or happiness in some manner. Once you have clicked on said 'upward pointing arrow' you should feel free to indulge yourself in whatever form of recreation you enjoy most, as your upvoting related tasks are now complete."

Comment: I mean yeah, your suggestion *works*, but we have a captive audience and we could make them... y'know... *do* things.

Comment: @devinb You could probably put whatever you want there.  It is pretty clear that no one reads it since the typo has been around so long.

Comment: ha ha - i guess i'm a 'no one'  :P

Comment: @Drew, you are a very special 'no one'.

Comment: @Drew, Everyone on Meta is that kind of 'no one'. We have a 'special' community here. Welcome! Join Us! Drink The Koolaid!

Comment: @Justin, @devinb, thank you - cheers - glug glug glug...

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely correct.  The text should be changed.